# How clean recently deleted apple notes with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

Since deleted notes get into the search, I want to delete them immediately and not wait 40 days! Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleted notes are moved into a folder `Recently Deleted`.

Just delete the notes in this folder

```
tell application "Notes"
    try
        delete every note in folder "Recently Deleted"
    end try
end tell
```

The `try` block ignores an error if there is no folder `Recently Deleted`